# extjs 4.1.3 group by first character

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

[image]

I have a grid which I want to group by the first character (with ftype : grouping)
I tried `groupField: 'country_name'[0]` in store but it doesn't work. How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

In your model create a new field and using `convert` set its value to the first character, then you can group by that new field.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i fixed the issue with php  : $tab->country[$nbrows]->FIRST_LETTER =  substr($p_cursor['COUNTRY_NAME'], 0, 1);